# Interface and model in TypeScript (angular 17)

Tags: angular, interface, nestjs-typeorm

Can someone help me with my code?

This is the Articlefournisseurs model:

```
import { Conditionnement } from "./conditionnements";
// import { IntefaceConditionnements, IntefaceConditionnement } from "./inteface-conditionnements";
import { InterfaceArticlefournisseurs } from "./interface-articlefournisseurs";

export class Articlefournisseur implements InterfaceArticlefournisseurs {
    id?: number | undefined;
    conditionnement: Conditionnement[];

    constructor(articlefournisseurInterface: InterfaceArticlefournisseurs) {
        this.conditionnement = articlefournisseurInterface.conditionnement;
    }
}
```

And this is the interface InterfaceArticlefournisseurs :

```
import { IntefaceConditionnements } from "./inteface-conditionnements";

export interface InterfaceArticlefournisseurs {
    id?: number,
    conditionnement: IntefaceConditionnements[]
}
```

This is the conditionnement model an interface:

```
export interface IntefaceConditionnement {
    id?: number,
    articleId: number,
    idUniteCommande: number,
    coefficientAchatCommande: number,
    idUniteAchat: number,
    coefficientInventaireAchat: number,
    iduniteInventaire: number,
    coefficientInventaire: number,
    idUniteFt: number,
    articlefournisseurId: number,
}
```

```
export interface IntefaceConditionnements {
    conditionnements: IntefaceConditionnement[];
}

import { IntefaceConditionnements, IntefaceConditionnement } from "./inteface-conditionnements";

export class Conditionnement implements IntefaceConditionnements {
    conditionnements: IntefaceConditionnement[];

    constructor(conditionnements: IntefaceConditionnement[]){
        this.conditionnements = conditionnements;
    }

    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        for (let conditionnement of this.conditionnements) {
            yield conditionnement;
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is when i tried to return Conditionnement data, i have the following error: Property '[Symbol.iterator]' is missing in type 'IntefaceConditionnements' but required in type 'Conditionnement'

I expect to have a data like this:

ArticleFournisseur.Conditionnement[0]: {...}
ArticleFournisseur.Conditionnement[1]: {...}

And use it in a loop in component html of my project.